# compare AES-256-CBC hash in golang decrypt

Tags: php, go, encryption, aes

I'm trying to compare the hash of a password, but when I compare it I get hieroglyphs and can't match whether it's true or false.

analog php function:

```
/*
  * Split hash into pieces
  * ([0] = ??, [1] = master key, [2] = salt len, [3] = salt, [4] = iteration count, [5] = salt position, [6] = ??, [7] == ??, [8] == ??)
  */
        $passHashArray = explode('$', $passHash);

        /*
         * Combine passphrase and salt
         */
        $passToHash = $testPassphrase.hex2bin($passHashArray[3]);


        /*
         * Hash $passToHash $passHasArray[4] times with SHA512
         */
        for($i = 0; $i < $passHashArray[4]; $i++){
            $passToHash = hash('SHA512', $passToHash, true);
        }
        
        /*
         * Get Key and Iv from $passToHash for final encryption
         */
        $key = substr($passToHash, 0, 32);
        $iv = substr($passToHash, 32, 16);
        
        /*
         * final passphrase encryption
         */
        if(in_array('aes-256-cbc', openssl_get_cipher_methods())){
            if(openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($passHashArray[1]), 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv)){
                 echo 'password correct';
            }else{
                echo 'decrypt failed';
            }
        }
```

go function:

```
var passwordHash = "64$718eadbd49dbee69e2b3e5f9659c361129cc07199d421d01892694477331ad8a$16$dce01545e0c918e7$76012$2$00$2$00"
var password = "12345678910"

func main()  {
        var passwordHashArray = strings.Split(passwordHash, "$")
    
        /*
         * Convert to hex to bin passphrase and salt
         */
        hex2Bin, err := hex.DecodeString(passwordHashArray[3])
    
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error hex decode string password hash array: %s", err)
        }
    
        /*
         * Combine passphrase and salt
         */
        passwordToHash  := strings.Join([]string{ password, string(hex2Bin)}, "")
    
        /*
         * Hash $passToHash $passHasArray[4] times with SHA512
         */
        intVar, err := strconv.Atoi(passwordHashArray[4])
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error password hash array string to int: %s", err)
        }
    
        passwordToHashBinary := make([]byte, 32)
        passwordToHashBinary = hashSHA512([]byte(passwordToHash))
    
        for i := 1; i < intVar; i++ {
            passwordToHashBinary = hashSHA512(passwordToHashBinary)
        }
    
        /*
         * Get Key and Iv from $passToHash for final encryption
         */
        var encKeyDecoded = make([]byte, 32)
             copy(encKeyDecoded, passwordToHashBinary[:32])
    
        var ivDecoded = make([]byte, 16)
            copy(ivDecoded, passwordToHashBinary[32:48])
    
        cipherTextDecoded, err := hex.DecodeString(passwordHashArray[1])
    
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error hex decode string password hash array: %s", err)
        }
    
        results, err := decrypt(cipherTextDecoded, encKeyDecoded, ivDecoded)
    
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error result decode password: %s", err)
        }
    
        log.Printf("%s", string(results))
        log.Printf("%x", string(results))
    }
    
    func decrypt(cipherTextDecoded []byte, encKeyDecoded []byte, ivDecoded []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    
        block, err := aes.NewCipher(encKeyDecoded)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    
        if len(cipherTextDecoded) < aes.BlockSize {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("ciphertext too short")
        }
    
        if len(cipherTextDecoded)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("ciphertext is not a multiple of the block size")
        }
    
        mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, ivDecoded)
    
        mode.CryptBlocks(cipherTextDecoded, cipherTextDecoded)
        return cipherTextDecoded, nil
    }
    
    func hashSHA512(crypto []byte) []byte  {
        hash := sha512.New()
        hash.Write(crypto)
        sha := hash.Sum(nil)
        return sha
    }
```

it is worth noting that in php the password is displayed correctly, but on the go I get a line like:

���Pʎ&L�t→]��f�►►►►►►►►►►►►►►►►

First of all, I don't understand where it comes from:

►►►►►►►►►►►►►►►►

How can I check if a password is valid in golang?

if () {good} else {bad}

out php:

https://onecompiler.com/php/3xqvgkhbr

out go:

https://go.dev/play/p/HUxoD29fM4c

Comment: On the Go side the PKCS#7 un-padding is missing which is the reason for the odd ending of your gibberish output. On the PHP side the un-padding happens implicitly, on the Go side it has to be implemented explicitly. A possible Go package can be found here https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/zenazn/pkcs7pad. Also, for a comparison of the data you should use a binary-to-text encoding like hex or Base64. Btw, more secure than a self-implemented key derivation would be a reliable one like Argon2 or PBKDF2.

Answer (score -1):

i never tried using AES on my site to store password but here's how i do it i'm using PDO prepared statement and bcrypt

```
    $read_username = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1");
    $read_username->execute([':username' => $username]);
    
        if ($read_username->rowCount() > === 1) {
            $row = $write_account->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $read_username = null; // close connection we already got what we need
            $pdo = null; // close connection we already got what we need
            $stored_hash = $row['password']; // bind the hash stored on db as $stored_hash 
            
            if (password_verify($password, $stored_hash)) { // compare user input to $stored_hash
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username . bin2hex(random_bytes(12));
                header('location: index.php');
                die("ACCESS GRANTED!");
                } else {
                    array_push($errors, "Incorrect password!");
                }
        } else {
        array_push($errors, "Account does not exist!");
        }
```

also your if else concern is easy it goes like this

```
$hotdog = 123;

if ($hotdog == 123) {
echo "hotdog";
} else {
echo "not hotdog";
}
```

Comment: but this is a little different, this is not a comparison of password on the site. this is a comparison of a password by hash, when the password is not exactly known, but only the hash is known

Comment: there is a dedicated package which basically does the same to implement authentication in go: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt. On user sign-up you get hash using `GenerateFromPassword` and store the hash to the db. On login you call `CompareHashAndPassword` to validate a password.

Comment: @serge-v
 , 
how will bcrypt verify a hash encrypted with CBC?)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer doesn't provide an answer to the question. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please answer the question directly. Do not just post a piece of your code without explenation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).